# How to convert an array into a string in javascript without the use of 'string()' function?

Tags: javascript

My array is

```
 var x = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

Can anyone help me convert this into string ? but I don't want to use `string()` function.

Comment: it's already a string ... LOL :D

Comment: *“I don't want to use 'string()' function”* why not?

Comment: see - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: You want `String.split()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: [How to split comma separated string using JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5269856), [How do I split a string, breaking at a particular character?](//stackoverflow.com/q/96428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join

```
var x = [1,2,3].join("");
console.log(typeof x);
console.log(x)
```

Split

```
 var text = "1,2,3";
 var array = text.split(",");
 console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this.You can also pass an empty argument

arr.join("")

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var A = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday']
array = A + ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method of JavaScript as below:

```
var x = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var a = document.getElementById("yourtargetdiv");
a.innerHTML = x.join();
```

Use join() instead of string()